# Inheriting Drag and Drop to the subclasses in JavaFX

Tags: java, inheritance, javafx, javafx-8

I have 8 classes inheriting from a superclass, they all have ImageViews in them and I want to implement drag and drop on all of them, they will be used all at once in a single scene. Is there any way to do that for the superclass, so that it get inherited to all the subclasses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new interface defining a methods for that event type (exampleEvent() addExampleEvent() removeExampleEventListener()). Implement this interface in the concrete class which generates these events.
It is better to use interfaces  ,don't use inheritence, it will lead to some problems that you surely dont want them.

Comment: The subclasses are inheriting from an abstract class. Should I add something like this parentClass implements newInterface{} and then implement the interface methods in each subclass?

Comment: Yes, just implement the methods when u need them.